# R ggplot - Error in self$geom$rename_size && "size" %in% names(plot$mapping) : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, printing

I currently inherited an .RData object with stored lists, dataframes, and ggplot objects. One such object is a ggplot object (of class gg and ggplot). The issue I am having is that if I type the object into the console, print the object in the console, or plot the object in the console I get the error, message described above. Side note: The exact specs for the ggplot object are as follows: `list [9] (S3: gg, ggplot)`

How can I plot this object without error?

```
> class(x)

gg ggplot
> x

Error in self$geom$rename_size && "size" %in% names(plot$mapping) : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
> print(x)

Error in self$geom$rename_size && "size" %in% names(plot$mapping) : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
> plot(x)

Error in self$geom$rename_size && "size" %in% names(plot$mapping) : 
  invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

Comment: It's not really possible to help without more information. Can you include the output of `dput(x)` in your question please? My guess is that either the ggplot is corrupt (e.g. by pointing to objects that were not saved), or that  you require an extension package that isn't loaded. There are a few other possibilities, but these really are just guesses, and can _only_ be guesses unless you can share the ggplot object.

Comment: I tried supplying the output, however, the contents are too large for Stack Overflow to be placed in the body of the question. Is there a way to store such info on StackOverflow and link to it?

Comment: You could try putting the output of `dput(x)` in pastebin, or a google document, or dropbox, and sharing the link I suppose.

Comment: I've recently encountered this error as well under similar circumstances (I have an .RData object that I am trying to call a plot from). In my case, I think the issue may be related to the `aes` mapping within the plot object, as the `x` and `y` variables are set to column names `x` and `y` in my dataframe (`aes(x = x, y = y, ...)`). Curious to know if this is the case in the issue raised here as well.